Create Atlas from themes
I am working in QGIS 3.38 and I would like to create a series of maps with atlas.
The difference would be that for all the series of maps the extension will be always the same but the layers and therefore data to display in every map would be different each time according to themes I have already added in the project.

I think doing something like this should work : https://woostuff.wordpress.com/2014/09/23/qgis-atlas-on-non-geometry-tables/ (basically create a table with a list of your theme, use this table as the atlas coverage layer and set your map to follow theme using data defined override with an expression like @atlas_pagename)
